How to port a PyCharm project from linux to windowsp
I have a python application for the command line which i built using PyCharm. To run it, i call source venv\bin\activate and then start my application with python my_app.py.
Now to port this to windows i copied the whole project directory (python files and venv) to  my PyCharmProjects directory. When i then tried to run my application from within pycharm, it didn't work because of missing packages. So i had to manually install all necessary packages again. Once the application ran in PyCharm, i wanted to test it on the command-line, but there is no activate.bat anywhere in my venv-directory, and there is also no .venv directory. I suppose i'll have similar issues when i go from windows back to linux again.
What is the correct way to port a Project from linux to windows (and vice versa)?

I would believe that you'd have to create the venv on your windows system.  Copying the venv from linux to windows won't work.

Here is the official Python tutorial how to install packages.

Dependencies are not copied with the project. Even if you copy the venv folder, a virtual environment created on one OS will not work correctly on another because the binaries and path to the Python interpreter are different.
Instead of transferring the virtual environment, create a file requirements.txt for dependencies. It is better to save a list of all installed packages in the only one file:
On the current os activate the virtual environment and create requirements.txt:
source venv/bin/activate
pip freeze > requirements.txt

Transfer only the project code and the requirements.txt file to the target system
After transferring the project to another system (windows or linux), create a new virtual environment and install all dependencies from this file:
python -m venv venv

Activate venv on Linux/Mac:
source venv/bin/activate

Activate venv on Windows:
venv\Scripts\activate

Install all packages
pip install -r requirements.txt

